# Missing Toolbox Items in VS 2013

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a WinForms application using Visual studio 2013. I have two user controls and 1 custom control in my project. Unfortunately for some reason they are not appearing in my toolbox at design. At one point they did briefly but disappeared and never returned. I have tried resetting the toolbox, checking the AutoPopulate option and made sure that my project is built. I've seen solutions about adding controls that exist in their own library but these exist within the same project. My classes also have a namespace and the ToolboxItem(True) attribute.

Thanks

Comment: And where's the question? Please provide a [MCVE], if possible. Try upgrading to a more recent Visual Studio, as the version you're using is very old.

Comment: I'm asking what I can do to get them to appear. Upgrading is also not an option.

Comment: To me it sounds like a bug. Try recreating the project or figure out the steps needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems there was an issue when trying to add some crystal reports control and I think it caused everything else to also not populate in the toolbox.